# Why is the ball glitching on the sidewalls unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to build a simple pong game. But everytime my ball touches the left or right wall, it glitches and gets kind of stuck in the wall on the sides.
this is the code to the ball.
i have the physics material friction set to 0 btw.

```
public float speed;
Vector2 direction;
Rigidbody2D rb;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    direction = Vector2.one.normalized;

}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.velocity = (direction * speed);
}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Walls"))
    {
        direction.y = -direction.y;
    }
    else if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        direction.x = -direction.x;
    }
```

Comment: When the ping ball hits the left and right side, you are changing its y direction(causing the code to work for the bottom and top walls), which will just cause it to hit the wall again and again.

Comment: @Chillipenguin Why didnt i think of that. Thank you i will make two separate tags for the x and y walls. Thanks  you man.

Comment: Why manually handle the direction change? If you are using the Unity physics system you can probably let Unity handle the bounce angles and just add some kind of starting force to your rigid body (you might want to call something like "rb.velocity = rb.velocity.normalize * speed;" in the update method so the ball doesn't stop due to unity weirdness).

Comment: I'll just leave it as is. It still worked tho.